# PHP: Give a name to an array of JSON objects?

Tags: php, json

I have managed to get data from database in PHP file.
From there(data.php),

```
$output = json_encode($result);
```

The result would be like this,

```
$output=[{"kitty":"Whitely"},{"kitty":"Tabby"},{"kitty":"Ruby"},{"kitty":"Silver"}]
```

So how do I give name "kitten" an array of kitty objects in php format?

For example like

```
"kitten":[{"kitty":"Whitely"},{"kitty":"Tabby"},{"kitty":"Ruby"},{"kitty":"Silver"}]
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to wrap your result in another array on the 'kitten' key :

```
$output = json_encode(['kitten' => $result]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$kitty = array('kitten' => array());
$kitty['kitty'][] = array('kitty' => 'Tabby');
$kitty['kitty'][] = array('kitty' => 'Ruby');
$kitty['kitty'][] = array('kitty' => 'Silver');

var_dump($kitty);
var_dump(json_encode($kitty));
```

which results in: `{"kitty":[{"kitty":"Tabby"},{"kitty":"Ruby"},{"kitty":"Silver"}]}`

Comment: @user1739825 See my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $result =array('kitten'=> $output);
```

*output*

```
{
"kitten":[
          {"kitty":"Whitely"},
          {"kitty":"Tabby"},
          {"kitty":"Ruby"},
          {"kitty":"Silver"}
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `encode` and `decode`

```
$json = '[{"kitty":"Whitely"},{"kitty":"Tabby"},{"kitty":"Ruby"},{"kitty":"Silver"}]';

echo json_encode(array('kitten' => json_decode($json)));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
$output['kitty'][] = json_encode($result);
```