# How can I convert an object to a specific JSON format?

Tags: php, json, object

json_encode converts an object to:

```
{
  "height":10,
  "width":20,
  "depth":5
}
```

But I need it to include the objects class name as well:

```
{
  "cuboid":
  {
    "height":10,
    "width":20,
    "depth":5
  }
}
```

Comment: use `json_encode(array('cuboid' => array( "height" => 10,
    "width"=>20,
    "depth"=>5) ))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Give a name to an array of JSON objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377469/php-give-a-name-to-an-array-of-json-objects)

Comment: What is your code stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function toJson() {
    return json_encode([get_class($this) => $this]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you out. Here we are converting `json` to `array` and putting it into an array of field `cuboid`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778571)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$json='{
  "height":10,
  "width":20,
  "depth":5
}';
$result["cuboid"]=json_decode($json,true);
echo json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_class](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.get-class.php) to get class name of an object.

```
$json = json_encode(array(get_class($object) => $object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rules for `json_encode`

- if you have an object it will be encode to `{'pro1':'value'}`
- if you have an array it will be encode to `['value']`
- if you have an string it will be encode to `'value'`

Note: *If you have an assoc-array in php, it becomes an object in json! If you have an index-array it will be an array in json.*  Dont mix index & assoc!

Test this bad pratice: `echo json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar',1,2));` Result is this bad syntax `{"kitten":"test","0":1,"1":2}` (propertie-names should NOT be numbers !!!)

So if you want and object under a property name do this

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->prop = array(1,2,'a');
$newObject = new stdClass();
$newObject->objname = $obj;

print_r(json_encode($newObject));
```

Becomes: `{'objname':{'prop':[1,2,'a']}}`

Have a nice day :-)